# Parsing variable number of lines

Tags: java, parsing, dictionary

I need to parse this kind of input:

- First line: contains an int value ***n*** ( ***1 <= n <= 26*** ) that indicates the number of symbols hereunder defined
- ***n*** lines formatted like the examples, values in the bracket can be only  ***0, 1,  .... , 9*** separated by blank-spaces. The first symbol is a character (*A, ... , Z*).

Each symbol (A-Z) defines a set containing all the values in the associated line. `{ }` represent an empty set. No one symbol can be repeated.

Examples of input:

```
3
Z = { 5 6 2 }
X = { 2 5 7 }
Y = { 2 4 3 0 }
```

or

```
2
X = { 7 }
Y = { }
```

I have to store these sets and identify them by the associated symbol. For reach my goal I used a java `Map` that stores <`set_id`, `set_values`> couples where each symbol is a `set_id` key for the map.

```
HashMap<Character, List<Integer>> sets = new HashMap<Character, List<Integer>>();
```

Here is the rest of the code. I wish someone could give me some advice to find another way and improve the performances.

```
    BufferedReader r =
            new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line = null;

    /* Stores couple <Set_id, Set_values> */
    HashMap<Character, List<Integer>> sets = new HashMap<Character, List<Integer>>();

    /* number of sets, first line parsed */
    int n_sets = Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());

    Character set_id = null;
    Character current = null;
    List<Integer> set_values = null;

    System.out.println("DEBUG: Will perform "+n_sets+" iteration");
    while(n_sets != 0){
        set_values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        line = r.readLine();
        set_id = new Character(line.charAt(0));

        /* Set input example : Z = { 5 6 2 } */
        for(int i=0; i<line.length(); i++){
            current = line.charAt(i);
            /* Fill values list for current set */
            if(Character.isDigit(current))
                set_values.add(Integer.parseInt(current.toString()));
        }

        /*Put current <set_id, set_values> into map */
        sets.put(set_id, set_values);
        -- n_sets;
    }
```

Comment: You seem to have a bug: All the entries in the map point to the same `ArrayList`.

Comment: Fixed! I forgot to clear the list on each iteration. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using split() to eliminate having to process the whitespace (which always fails your criteria anyway)

```
    String[] splitLine = line.split(" ");
    for(int i=0; i<splitLine.length; i++){
                if (Character.isDigit(splitLine[i].charAt(0)))
                   set_values.add(Integer.parseInt(current.toString()));
            }
```

Comment: Sorry but i can't figure out how your alternative make use of regular expressions.

Comment: I misspoke. What my alternative does is use the split() method, which is technically a way of using regular expressions.

In any case, my solution eliminates whitespace from your checks. Removing the first and last elements of the array would remove two more checks.